# How to select optional parameters on oracle (Decrease execution time of oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, parameters, case-when

I have to decrease execution time of this. This statement processing waste about 30 minutes when I just inserted on ":i_member_name", all other is null.

```
SELECT 

A.MEMBER_NUM, A.MEMBER_NAME, B.MEMBER_INFO FROM REG_MEMBER A, MEMBER_DETAIL B

WHERE A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID 

AND (LOWER(A.MEMBER_NAME)  LIKE LOWER(:i_member_name || '%'))     

AND (LOWER(B.MEMBER_INFO) LIKE LOWER(:i_member_info || '%'))

AND (A.MEMBER_NUM  LIKE :i_member_num || '%')

AND (LOWER(B.MEMBER_ADD) LIKE LOWER('%' || :i_member_add || '%'))
```

If I execute like this it's being ok just wasted 30 seconds.

```
SELECT 

    A.MEMBER_NUM, A.MEMBER_NAME, B.MEMBER_INFO FROM REG_MEMBER A, MEMBER_DETAIL B

    WHERE A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID 

    AND (LOWER(A.MEMBER_NAME)  LIKE LOWER(:i_member_name || '%'))     

  --AND (LOWER(B.MEMBER_INFO) LIKE LOWER(:i_member_info || '%'))

  --AND (A.MEMBER_NUM  LIKE :i_member_num || '%')

  --AND (LOWER(B.MEMBER_ADD) LIKE LOWER('%' || :i_member_add || '%'))
```

So I have a question: How to check parameter is null then don't read against more execution time. something like this

```
         SELECT A.MEMBER_NUM, A.MEMBER_NAME, B.MEMBER_INFO FROM REG_MEMBER A, MEMBER_DETAIL B         
                    WHERE 
(LOWER(A.MEMBER_NAME)  LIKE LOWER(:i_member_name || '%'))    
         and   case when :i_member_num is null then return 
        else (A.MEMBER_NUM LIKE :i_member_num || '%')
    end
```

Comment: Use boolean logic. Change `AND (LOWER(B.MEMBER_INFO) LIKE LOWER(:i_member_info || '%'))` to `(AND (LOWER(B.MEMBER_INFO) LIKE LOWER(:i_member_info || '%')) OR :i_member_info IS NULL)`. This may not make a difference though - you need to use the query plan to check

Comment: Perhaps there's another way - create an index on `lower(member_name)` etc.? Since you must wrap within `lower()`, an index on `member_name` itself will not help.

Comment: Can you specify me more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to check for optional parameters in SQL is usually with `NVL`.

Oracle can often expand an `NVL` expression into two separate sub-plans.  A `FILTER` operation will work at run time to choose only one part of the plan.  For example, it may use an `INDEX RANGE SCAN` with a bind value like `'Smith%'` that is sargable; and it may use a `TABLE ACCESS FULL` with a bind value like `NULL` that is not sargable.

Below is an example using a small subset of the objects in your question:

```
--Create table and index.
create table reg_member(member_num number, member_name varchar2(100));
create index reg_member_idx on reg_member(lower(member_name));

--Generate explain plan.
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT
    A.MEMBER_NUM, A.MEMBER_NAME
FROM REG_MEMBER A
WHERE NVL(:i_member_name, LOWER(A.MEMBER_NAME)) = LOWER(A.MEMBER_NAME);

--Show explain plan.
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 3501926772

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                 |     2 |   130 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  VIEW                                  | VW_ORE_377C5901 |     2 |   130 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL                            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    FILTER                              |                 |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| REG_MEMBER      |     1 |   117 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | REG_MEMBER_IDX  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |    FILTER                              |                 |       |       |            |          |
|*  7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | REG_MEMBER      |     1 |   117 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter(:I_MEMBER_NAME IS NOT NULL)
   5 - access(LOWER("MEMBER_NAME")=:I_MEMBER_NAME)
   6 - filter(:I_MEMBER_NAME IS NULL)
   7 - filter(LOWER("MEMBER_NAME") IS NOT NULL)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

`NVL` `FILTER` operations can work great in some cases.  But it's difficult to say if it would fix your specific problem because there are so many variables: do the objects have the right indexes, how do all the predicates work together, etc.  But `NVL` is a good place to start.

Comment: Do I need Generate explain plan for all other parameter? /:i_member_info, :i_member_add,  :i_member_num /
Should I need to create index for each one?

Comment: @user2801618 You only need to use `EXPLAIN PLAN` to check the plan.  Since your query could potentially use any combination of the columns I think it would make sense to index all the relevant columns and expressions.

Comment: 'create index reg_member_idx on reg_member(lower(member_name));
create index reg_member_idx2 on reg_member(lower(i_member_num ));
create index reg_member_idx3 on reg_member(lower(i_member_add));' Like this?